# Integral with parameter: $\int_{0}^{a}x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integral :

$$\int_{0}^{a}x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$

I tried to manipulate the integral and then use substitution to get a rational form to arrive at:

$$-8a^4\int_0^a \frac{t(1-t^2)^2}{(1+t^2)^5}dt$$

I am stuck here and I can't find a mistake in my computations. Or maybe there's a better way to proceed.

I'd be grateful for any advice.
Thanks

Comment: Substitute $x = a\sin \varphi$ for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got $\frac{a^4\pi}{16}$ which matches with Wolfram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

$x=ay=a\sin \varphi$

Then

$
\int_{0}^{a}dxx^{2}\sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}=a^{4}\int_{0}^{1}dyy^{2}\sqrt{1-y^{2}}%
=a^{4}\int_{0}^{\pi /2}d\varphi \cos \varphi \sin ^{2}\varphi \cos \varphi
$

I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it from here. My result is $\frac{a^4\pi}{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = a\sin \theta$. Note that, $dx = a\cos \theta d\theta$.
$$
\int_{0}^{a} x^2\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} (a\sin \theta)^2\sqrt{a^2 - a^2\sin^2 \theta}\ a \cos \theta d\theta 
$$
$$
= \dfrac{a^4}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} 4\sin^2\theta \cos^2 \theta d\theta = \dfrac{a^4}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^2(2\theta) d \theta = \dfrac{a^4}{8}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}[1 - \cos(4\theta)]d\theta
$$
$$
= \dfrac{a^4}{8}\biggl[\theta - \dfrac{1}{4}\sin(4\theta)\biggr ]_{0}^{\pi/2} = \dfrac{\pi a^4}{16}
$$

Comment: Is your result correct? Because I got a different result, which corresponds with wolfram's result.

Comment: You replaced $dx$ by $d\theta$, but it must be $dx = d(a\sin\theta) = a\cos\theta \,d\theta$.